# How can I animate a <path> object in SVG

Tags: svg, path, jquery-animate, svg-animate

```
<g id = "doc">

        /*Doc*/
        <path d = "M 100 100 L 150 100 L 170 120 L 170 190 L 100 190 L 100 100 Z M 150 100 L 150 120              
            L 170 120 M 120 140 L 150 140  M 120 160 L 150 160" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "8px"  fill = "white" transform = "translate(350, 110)">

        </path>

</g>

    <animate xlink:href = "#doc" attributeName = "x" from = "450" to = "1000" dur = "4" repeatCount = "indefinite" />
```

If I try to animate the  with the id = "doc", which is located inside a  tag, the animation is not working. Thanks for help!

Comment: There's no x attribute in a path to animate. What are you trying to achieve? Do you really want an animateTransform with a translate transform?

Comment: I have drawn a "document-icon" with the path and now I want to move the whole <path> - element from x = 450 to x = 1000.

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SVG *was* a bloated file icon:

[image]

The only animation I can think of is:

[image]

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 90 110" style="background:pink;height:180px">
   <path d="m10 10 50 0 20 20 0 70-70 0 0-90zm50 0 0 20 20 0m-50 20 30 0m-30 20 30 0" 
         stroke="black" stroke-width="8px" fill="white">
     <animatemotion path="m0 0h100" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </path>                  
</svg>
```

#### Update - `animationMotion` doesn't work in Chrome `IMG` and `OBJECT` tags

`animationMotion` **does** work inside an `IMG` tag in FireFox

To make it work in Chrome, change it to an `animateTransform` animation

Since my favorite pastime on a lazy Sunday is to clean SVGs, here is your code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1320 520" style="background:pink" fill="black" stroke="black">
    <g id="deviceleft">
        <rect x="355" y="80" width="12" height="85" rx="5" />
        <rect x="355" y="185" width="12" height="40" rx="5" />
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="350" height="500" stroke-width="5" rx="10" fill="lightblue" />
        <circle cx="335" cy="35" r="8" fill="grey" stroke-width="7" />
    </g>
    <g id="deviceright">
        <rect x="1305" y="110" width="12" height="85" rx="5" />
        <rect x="1305" y="210" width="12" height="40" rx="5" />
        <rect x="1010" y="60" width="300" height="400" fill="grey" stroke-width="5" rx="10" />
        <rect x="1105" y="60" width="110" height="25" rx="10" />
        <circle cx="1185" cy="72" r="6" stroke="grey" stroke-width="4" />
        <rect x="1135" y="68" width="35" height="8" fill="darkgrey" rx="5" />
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0 175)">
        <path d="m435 60 500 0m-1 0-19-10m19 10-19 10" stroke-width="6" />
        <path d="m385 20 50 0 20 20 0 70-70 0 0-90zm50 0 0 20 20 0m-50 20 30 0m-30 20 30 0" stroke-width="8"
            fill="white">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="4s" values="50 0;450 0"
                repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However when I try to implement your code in my File it is not working... Maybe you have time to look at my code :

Comment: When hit "Run code snippet" in your browser it runs? Then there is something wrong in your file.